# Reroute to login page in nginx

Tags: angular

I have deployed my application using Nginx. **My app URL is user-connect.in** After logged in the URL changes to **user-connect.in/home**. If I change the URL address to user-connect.in/homeasdasd(a random name)  it should get redirected to the login page.

But what actutally happens is that it shows 404 Not found Error nginx/1.19.2[image].I tried the same thing in localhost but it gets redirected to localhost.I dont know how to achieve the same thing after deploying my application using nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you setup URL rewrite rules in your nginx.conf?

```
location / {
   try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
}
```

This will return index.html instead of 404 when there is a URL that does not exist on the server, so that Angular routes can take over client-side.

Comment: I don't think I did it.